# Xcode 8.3.2 and IOS 10.3.1 Does not Connect to Network When Running As Developer (using AlamoFire)

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, alamofire

I am writing an IOS App which uses AlamoFire to connect to and login to my server.  The app connects fine on a simulator.  However, ever since I upgraded my test phone to IOS 10.3.1 and my Xcode to 8.3.2, I get the following network error when trying to log into my remote server:

"you had a failure with Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x174249e70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https:" ...

Are there any known issues with IOS 10.3.1 blocking network calls...maybe an AlamoFire issue?